# mapPartitionsWithIndex - how is output combined

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to understand `mapPartitionsWithIndex` in Spark. I found that the following two examples produce vastly different output:

```
parallel = sc.parallelize(range(1,10),2)
def show(index, iterator): yield 'index: '+str(index)+" values: "+ 
str(list(iterator))
parallel.mapPartitionsWithIndex(show).collect()


parallel = sc.parallelize(range(1,10),2)
def show(index, iterator): return 'index: '+str(index)+" values: "+ 
str(list(iterator))
parallel.mapPartitionsWithIndex(show).collect()
```

As highlighted, the difference lies in whether the show function returns a generator or an iterator.

I guess I do not understand how `mapPartitionsWithIndex` combines the results from the individual partitions.

Can you please explain to me how this behavior occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapPartitionsWithIndex(self, f, preservesPartitioning=False)
```

The parameter: `f` must return an **iterable** object.

In general it should be raise an error if there is no iterable object returned.

But in your case2,  `return String` is turned into `return list of letter` by mistake through `iterator = iter(iterator)` in source code(pyspark/serializers.py, line 266).

Just `return ["I'm String"]` if you insist on using `return`.